# Which NoSQL databases support text array columns (and indexes on this columns) like the postgreSQL text[] type?

Tags: nosql

I need to move data from a postgreSQL to a NoSQL database, in the process we are evaluating different NoSQL databases and Cassandra came up as a possibility but from the documentation it seems like Cassandra doesn't support having a text array as a column type, is this correct? Which NoSQL databases support this type of columns and support indexes on this type of columns?

For example to store this and have an index on a column with this type of data:

```
City:['Washington','Washington DC']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MongoDB allows to create indices on array-fields. But why do you **need** too move data from postgreSQL to another database technology?

Comment: Because the db is big now and the cost of having it in a single(expensive) server running at the speed we need is more than the cost of setting up a NoSQL cluster for the db using less expensive servers.

Comment: Sounds like you're not utilizing memory caching techniques like memcache sufficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question (not enough reputation to comment (?!?)), but understanding that your problem is scale, and you are coming from PostgreSQL, have you tried PostgresXC yet?  That may be a much easier transition than to NoSQL.  NoSQL databases, as I assume you know, have very different performance characteristics and nuances that might actually do more harm than good.  Postgres-XC is a multi-master write-scalable fork  of PostgreSQL and sits somewhere between 9.1 and 9.2 from a PostgreSQL feature standpoint and it is an active project.  9.2 conformance was slated this month or last if I recall correctly.  It's relatively easy to set up for what it is - you'll build 2 GTM's, one as a primary and one as a failover, give them enough memory.  Then you can scale horizontally by adding pairs of coordinators and data nodes, 1 coordinator and 1 data node per server.  Your application tier can talk to any of the coordinators, transactions are shipped to the appropriate coordinators and you can specify the distribution of your data by table - either replicated for small reference tables or distributed for large ones.  If you design your queries well, you can get massive performance improvement because your queries can be shipped and executed simultaneously on multiple coordinator/data node pairs.

I know you are looking for NoSQL, but I mention this because we too had a vertical vs horizontal scale problem and in the end I found it was easier to build NoSQL capability into a relational system than it was to build relational capability into a NoSQL system.  And of course it all depends on your data, sometimes NoSQL is absolutely the best choice.  Sometimes it can be a major headache too, for example some NoSQL databases have problems with filesystem growth so whereas you thought you bought horizontal scalability you wound up eating your SAN out of house and home.

Anyway, hope that helps!  I would have left it as a comment but stackoverflow has that strange reputation thing going on.

I forgot to mention also, with Postgres-XC you can specify on which columns you wish to distribute and by what kind of algorithm.  I typically distribute by hash, and make sure of two things, first that hash can be generated application-side so that I don't have to do joins on tables that are gadzillions of rows and second that the hash keeps the distribution level across servers correct but while also keeping related information together on the same server so as to increase the shippability of queries.  That is, if you have a customer table and a customer orders table, distribute both on a hash of some customer unique information that is in both tables and make sure you can generate that application-side.  I hope that makes sense, I'm not sure if I did a good job explaining.  If you would like further clarification on that please let me know, the docs are a bit scattered on XC right now, so a lot of what I related is OJT.